# Running WinDbg in headless mode

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, windbg, crash-dumps

Is there a way to WinDbg in pure headless mode ? 
My use case is that I should be able to imitate "!analyze -v" command for a minidump on command line without launching WinDbg GUI.

Comment: How about using cdb as your debugger (console version of WinDbg) and then configure the default debugger in the registry to launch:   `cdb.exe -c "!analyze -v" -p %ld -e %ld`

Comment: Let me give it a shot. Thanks for your prompt response

Comment: So I found cdb to be useful and serving my purpose. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

With the Debugging Tools for Windows, there is also `cdb`, the console debugger.

To debug a crash dump, use the `-z "<dump>"` option. To run a command immediately, use `-c "<command>"`. To output everything into a file you can redirect the output with a usual DOS `> <file>` or open a log file using `.logopen <file>`. To exit CDB after the analysis, use `q`.

You want to make sure that you have symbols set up correctly, so include a `.symfix <path>;.reload`. I prefer using `.symfix <symbolpath>` in the command rather than `-y <symbolpath>`, so I can always check in the log that it has been set correctly.

Full command line (using redirect)

```
"<windbgpath>\cdb.exe" -z "<dumpfile>" -c ".symfix <symbolpath>;.reload;!analyze -v;q" > "<logfile>"
```

Disadvantage of redirect: line ending is `LF` only. And you get a lot of noise when the debugger starts.

Full command line (using log file)

```
"<windbgpath>\cdb.exe" -z "<dumpfile>" -c ".logopen <logfile>;.symfix <symbolpath>;.reload;!analyze -v;.logclose;q"
```